# PowerShell5. Modify ascii text file string with line number string is on. Switch and .NET framework or cmdlets & the pipeline? Which is faster?

Tags: performance, powershell, replace, file-io, powershell-5.0

How to modify a string (LINE2 "line number LINE2 is on") in a windows ascii text file using search strings that are easy to read and easy to add/modify/delete using PowerShell 5.  This script will parse a 2500 line file, find 139 instances of the strings, replace them and overwrite the original in less than 165ms on average depending on which method you use.  Which method is faster? Which method is easier to add/modify/delete the strings?

Search for strings "AROUND LINE {1-9999}" and "LINE2 {1-9999}" and replace {1-9999} with the {line number} the code is on. The tests were done with a 2500 line file not the two line sample.bat.

sample.bat contains two lines:

```
ECHO AROUND LINE 5936
TITLE %TIME%   DISPLAY TCP-IP SETTINGS   LINE2 5937
```

**Method One: Using Get-Content + -replace + Set-Content:**

```
Measure-command {
copy-item $env:temp\sample9.bat -d $env:temp\sample.bat -force
(gc $env:temp\sample.bat) | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace 'AROUND LINE \d+', "AROUND LINE $lc" -replace 'LINE2 \d+', "LINE2 $lc"
  ++$lc
} | sc -Encoding Ascii $env:temp\sample.bat}
```

**Results: 175ms-387ms in ten runs for an average of 215ms.**

You modify the search by adding / removing / modifying -replace.

`-replace 'AROUND LINE \d+', "AROUND LINE $lc" -replace 'LINE2 \d+', "LINE2 $lc" -replace 'PLACEMARK \d+', "PLACEMARK $lc"`

**powershell $env:temp\sample.ps1 $env:temp\sample.bat**:

`(gc $args[0]) | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace 'AROUND LINE \d+', "AROUND LINE $lc" -replace 'LINE2 \d+', "LINE2 $lc"
  ++$lc
} | sc -Encoding Ascii $args[0]`

**Method Two:  Using switch and .NET frameworks:**

```
Measure-command {
    copy-item $env:temp\sample9.bat -d $env:temp\sample.bat -force
    $file = "$env:temp\sample.bat"
    $lc = 0
    $updatedLines = switch -Regex ([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)) {
      '^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$' { $Matches[1] + ++$lc + $Matches[2] }
      default { ++$lc; $_ }
    }
    [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)}
```

**Results: 73ms-816ms in ten runs for an average of 175ms.**

**Method Three:  Using switch and .NET frameworks optimized version based on a precompiled regex:**

```
Measure-command {
copy-item $env:temp\sample9.bat -d $env:temp\sample.bat -force
$file = "$env:temp\sample.bat"
$regex = [Regex]::new('^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')
$lc = 0
$updatedLines = & {foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($file)) {
    $lc++
    $m = $regex.Match($line)
    if ($m.Success) {
        $g = $m.Groups
        $g[1].Value + $lc + $g[2].Value
    } else { $line }
}}
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)}
```

**Results: 71ms-236ms in ten runs for an average of 106ms.**

Add/Modify/Delete your search string:

```
AROUND LINE|LINE2|PLACEMARK
AROUND LINE|LINE3
LINE4
```

**powershell $env:temp\sample.ps1 $env:temp\sample.bat**:

```
$file=$args[0]
$regex = [Regex]::new('^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')
    $lc = 0
    $updatedLines = & {foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($file
)) {
        $lc++
        $m = $regex.Match($line)
        if ($m.Success) {
            $g = $m.Groups
            $g[1].Value + $lc + $g[2].Value
        } else { $line }
    }}
    [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file
, $updatedLines, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

<sup>*Editor's note*: This is a follow-up question to [Iterate a backed up ascii text file, find all instances of {LINE2 1-9999} replace with {LINE2 "line number the code is on"}. Overwrite. Faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54737787/45375)</sup>

<sup>*The evolution of this question from youngest to oldest:*
 1. [54757890](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757890) 2. [54737787](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737787) 3. [54712715](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712715) 4. [54682186](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682186)</sup>

<sup>*Update*: I've used @mklement0 regex solution.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch -Regex -File $file {
  '^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$' { $Matches[1] + ++$lc + $Matches[2] }
  default { ++$lc; $_ }
}
```

- Given that regex `^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$` contains only *2* capture groups - the part of the line *before* the number to replace (`\d+`) and the part of the line *after*, you must reference these groups with indices `1` and `2` into the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#matches) in the output (not `2` and `3`).

  - Note that `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing* group, so by design it isn't reflected in `$Matches`.
- Instead of reading the file with `[IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)`, I'm using the `-File` option with `switch`, which directly reads the lines from file `$file`.
- The `++$lc` inside `default { ++$lc; $_ }` ensures that the line counter is also incremented for *non-matching* lines before passing the line at hand through (`$_`).

---

#### Performance notes

- You can improve the performance slightly with the following [obscure optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776311/45375):

  ```
  # Enclose the switch statement in & { ... } to speed it up slightly.
  $updatedLines = & { switch -Regex -File ... }
  ```
- With high iteration counts (a large number of lines), using a *precompiled `[regex]` instance* rather than a *string literal* that PowerShell converts to a regex behind the scenes can speed things up further - see benchmarks below.
- Additionally, if case-*sensitive* matching is sufficient, you can squeeze out *a little* more performance by adding the `-CaseSensitive` option to the `switch` statement.
- At a high level, **what makes the solution fast is the use of `switch -File` to process the lines**, and, generally, the **use of .NET types for file I/O** (rather than cmdlets) (`IO.File]::WriteAllLines()` in this case, as shown in the question) - see also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54753717/45375).

  - That said, [marsze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54789869/45375) offers a highly optimized `foreach` loop approach based on a precompiled regex that is faster with *higher iteration counts* - it is, however, more verbose.

---

#### Benchmarks

- The following code compares the performance of this answer's `switch` approach with marsze's `foreach` approach.
- Note that in order to make the two solutions fully equivalent, the following tweaks were made:

  - The `& { ... }` optimization was added to the `switch` command as well.
  - The `IgnoreCase` and `CultureInvariant` options were added to the `foreach` approach to match the options PS regexes *implicitly* use.

Instead of a 6-line sample file, performance is tested with a 600-line, a 3,000 and a 30,000-line file respectively, so as to show the effects of the iteration count on performance.

100 runs are being averaged.

**Sample results** from my Windows 10 machine running Windows PowerShell v5.1 - the *absolute* times aren't important, but hopefully the *relative* performance shown in the `Factor` column is generally representative:

```
VERBOSE: Averaging 100 runs with a 600-line file of size 0.03 MB...

Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.023               # switch -Regex -File with regex string literal...
1.16   0.027               # foreach with precompiled regex and [regex].Match...
1.23   0.028               # switch -Regex -File with precompiled regex...


VERBOSE: Averaging 100 runs with a 3000-line file of size 0.15 MB...

Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.063               # foreach with precompiled regex and [regex].Match...
1.11   0.070               # switch -Regex -File with precompiled regex...
1.15   0.073               # switch -Regex -File with regex string literal...


VERBOSE: Averaging 100 runs with a 30000-line file of size 1.47 MB...

Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.252               # foreach with precompiled regex and [regex].Match...
1.24   0.313               # switch -Regex -File with precompiled regex...
1.53   0.386               # switch -Regex -File with regex string literal...
```

Note how at lower iteration counts `switch -regex` with a *string literal* is fastest, but at around 1,500 lines the `foreach` solution with a precompiled `[regex]` instance starts to get faster; using a precompiled `[regex]` instance with `switch -regex` pays off to a lesser degree, only with higher iteration counts.

**Benchmark code**, using the [`Time-Command` function](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

```
# Sample file content (6 lines)
$fileContent = @'
TITLE %TIME%   NO "%zmyapps1%\*.*" ARCHIVE ATTRIBUTE   LINE2 1243
TITLE %TIME%   DOC/SET YQJ8   LINE2 1887
SET ztitle=%TIME%: WINFOLD   LINE2 2557
TITLE %TIME%   _*.* IN WINFOLD   LINE2 2597
TITLE %TIME%   %%ZDATE1%% YQJ25   LINE2 3672
TITLE %TIME%   FINISHED. PRESS ANY KEY TO SHUTDOWN ... LINE2 4922

'@

# Determine the full path to a sample file.
# NOTE: Using the *full* path is a *must* when calling .NET methods, because
#       the latter generally don't see the same working dir. as PowerShell.
$file = "$PWD/test.bat"

# Note: input is the number of 6-line blocks to write to the sample file,
#       which amounts to 600 vs. 3,000 vs. 30,0000 lines.
100, 500, 5000 | % { 

  # Create the sample file with the sample content repeated N times.
  $repeatCount = $_ 
  [IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $fileContent * $repeatCount)

  # Warm up the file cache and count the lines.
  $lineCount = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file).Count

  # Define the commands to compare as an array of scriptblocks.
  $commands =
    { # switch -Regex -File with regex string literal
      & { 
        $i = 0
        $updatedLines = switch -Regex -File $file {
          '^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$' { $Matches[1] + ++$i + $Matches[2] }
          default { ++$i; $_ }
        } 
        [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [text.encoding]::ASCII)
      }
    }, { # switch -Regex -File with precompiled regex
      & {
        $i = 0
        $regex = [Regex]::new('^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')
        $updatedLines = switch -Regex -File $file {
          $regex { $Matches[1] + ++$i + $Matches[2] }
          default { ++$i; $_ }
        } 
        [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [text.encoding]::ASCII)
      }
    }, { # foreach with precompiled regex and [regex].Match
      & {
        $regex = [Regex]::new('^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')
        $i = 0
        $updatedLines = foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($file)) {
            $i++
            $m = $regex.Match($line)
            if ($m.Success) {
                $g = $m.Groups
                $g[1].Value + $i + $g[2].Value
            } else { $line }
        }
        [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)    
      }
    }

  # How many runs to average.
  $runs = 100

  Write-Verbose -vb "Averaging $runs runs with a $lineCount-line file of size $('{0:N2} MB' -f ((Get-Item $file).Length / 1mb))..."

  Time-Command -Count $runs -ScriptBlock $commands | Out-Host

}
```

Comment: For more explanation of regex by mklement0 see [54757890](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757890)

Comment: Very accurate work. Most files probably won't be that large, and the switch version is also easier to write. So I guess your solution is still the way to go. Kudos.

Comment: It *will* work if you construct it like this: `$regex = [Regex]::new('^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')` (Based on IISResetMe's Github comment.) Was about 20% faster in my benchmark. Yay, even more switch-boost ;)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @marsze (I hope I got it right this time): Yes, after ruling out the effects from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8911, using a precompiled regex with `switch -regex` does help at higher iteration counts, but using a precompiled regex with your `foreach` + `.Match()` solution is the clear winner at higher iteration counts - please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```
$regex = [Regex]::new('^(.*? (?:AROUND LINE|LINE2) )\d+(.*)$', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')
$lc = 0
$updatedLines = & {foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($file)) {
    $lc++
    $m = $regex.Match($line)
    if ($m.Success) {
        $g = $m.Groups
        $g[1].Value + $lc + $g[2].Value
    } else { $line }
}}
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

Comment: Nicely done; depending on the line count, this optimized version based on a precompiled regex has the potential to be faster - please see the benchmarks I've added to my answer.