# Select host names from log files

Tags: powershell

I have an application that generates 100's of text log files which are like

```
DaemonReruns=2|

Phase=|

Log=false|
DS=LOG_4|
Schema=LOLYY|
DBMS=mssql|
Host=abc.XYz.com|
IDs=xxxxx,xxxx
```

I need to select Host from these
I tried

```
GC  C:\log_5.txt |
    Select-String -Pattern 'Host=\"([^\"]*)\"'
```

Gives no results, any help ?

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any quotes in your example input. Try this regex:

```
get-content C:\log_5.txt | foreach {
    if ($_ -match 'Host=([^|]+)') {
        $Matches.1
    }
}
```

*Note: This actually returns the host names, not just the line.*

Comment: Cool it works but not able to sort unique 
`
gci C:\logs|
where{$_.Extension -like '*.txt' -or $_.Extension -like '*.proc'} |Foreach{Get-Content $_.FullName}|
    foreach {
    if ($_ -match 'Host=([^|]+)') {
        $data=$Matches.1
        $data|Sort-Object -Unique
    }
}
`

Comment: @Jondrew Put the sort at the very end of the pipeline: `... { $Matches.1 } } | sort -Unique`

Comment: it wont

`foreach {
    if ($_ -match 'Host=([^|]+)') {
        $Matches.1  | sort -Unique
    }
}`

Comment: @Jondrew `foreach { if ($_ -match 'Host=([^|]+)') { $Matches.1 } } | sort -Unique`

Answer (score 3):

[marsze's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887996/45375) fixes the problem with your regex and uses a `ForEach-Object` (`foreach`) call to extract and return matches via the `-match` operator and the automatic `$Matches` variable.

Here's a concise (and better-performing) alternative using the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch):

```
PS> switch -Regex -File C:\log_5.txt { 'Host=([^|]+)' { $Matches[1] } }
abc.XYz.com
```

Note that `-File` doesn't accept wildcard-based paths, however, so in order to process multiple file, you'll have to loop over them via `Get-ChildItem` or `Convert-Path`.

Answer (score 2):

```
((Get-Content -Path .\log_5.txt) -match 'Host=') -replace 'Host=',''
```

returns all the lines starting with `Host=`

Comment: cool,, its coming with Host=abc.domain.com|

can we exclude Host= and | just need the url

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun ... the [super-fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777449/2060966) solution:

```
$regex = [Regex]::new('Host=([^|]+)', 'Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant')
& {foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\log_5.txt")) {
    $m = $regex.Match($line)
    if ($m.Success) {
        $m.Groups[1].Value
    }
}}
```

Comment: Btw, it seems that what slows `switch -Regex` down relative to `[regex].Match()` is the additional effort of translating the match information into the `$Matches` hashtable.

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah PS is still a scripting language made to be easily usable, not fast. If I write the same in C# code, compile it with `Add-Type` and call that, it's a few dozen times faster.

Comment: Nice C# solution; another brief tangent: here's a fun pitfall with `switch -File`: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8988

Answer (score 2):

If your logs are huge, it could be worth the overhead of `Add-Type`, and the rest would be much faster:

```
Add-Type '
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace PowerShell
{
    public class Tools
    {
        static Regex regex = new Regex(@"Host=([^|]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetHosts(string path)
        {
            foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path))
            {
                var matches = regex.Match(line);
                if (matches.Success)
                {
                    yield return matches.Groups[1].Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

# call this for each log file (very fast)
[PowerShell.Tools]::GetHosts("C:\log_5.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have the regex side covered well enough. Whenever I see little logs like this I always think about `ConvertFrom-StringData` which

> converts a string that contains one or more key and value pairs into a hash table.
>
> <sup>From: help ConvertFrom-StringData</sup>

In its basic form we just do something like this:

```
$pairs = Get-Content -Raw -File $pathtofile | ConvertFrom-StringData
[pscustomobject]$pairs
```

Which would give you a PowerShell object that you can interact with easily!

```
DS           : LOG_4|
Schema       : LOLYY|
IDs          : xxxxx,xxxx
Log          : false|
DBMS         : mssql|
Host         : abc.XYz.com|
Phase        : |
DaemonReruns : 2|
```

Doubtful that you need the trailing pipes. You can remove those with some regex or simpler string methods.

```
[pscustomobject](Get-Content -File $pathToFile | ForEach-Object{$_.trimend("|")} | Out-string | ConvertFrom-StringData)

[pscustomobject]((Get-Content -Raw -File $pathToFile) -replace "(?m)\|$" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
```

---

In any case this gives you more options as to how you need to deal with your data.